# In WSL2 unable to run custom pre-commit githook

Tags: githooks, husky

Firstly, thanks for any and all responses given. And I'm sorry if I have not included helpful relevant information.

I am trying to configure a pre-commit githook (lint, prettify and test) without the need for adding `husky` and `lint-staged` as dependencies, but I am not having much luck.

As per the instructions included in the resources below, I have added a `post-install` script which reconfigures the `hooksPath` (see below).

`"postinstall": "git config core.hooksPath ./git-hooks"`

Now the problem arises that `STAGED_FILES` uses the relative path of each staged file as its path reference. And, because I am running Ubuntu on WSL2 this will not work (for reasons I am hoping someone can explain to me). The result of running `git-hooks/pre-commit` from cli is `[error] No files matching the pattern were found: "LIST_OF_STAGED_FILES"` with LIST_OF_STAGED_FILES being a string, e.g. "src/index.js src/anotherFile.js ..."

**./git-hooks/pre-commit**

```
#!/bin/sh
STAGED_FILES=$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR | sed 's| |\\ |g')

# run linter on staged files
echo "Running Linter..⚒️⚒️⚒️"
./node_modules/.bin/eslint $STAGED_FILES --quiet --fix
LINTER_EXIT_CODE=$?

# run Prettier on staged files
echo "Running Prettier..✨✨✨"
./node_modules/.bin/prettier $STAGED_FILES --ignore-unknown --write

# add files auto-fixed by the linter and prettier
git add -f $STAGED_FILES

# check linter exit code
if [ $LINTER_EXIT_CODE -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "No, no, no! fix those lint errors first.."
    exit 1
else
    echo "lint all good.."
fi

# run tests related to staged files
echo "Running Tests"
./node_modules/.bin/jest --bail --findRelatedTests $STAGED_FILES --passWithNoTests
JEST_EXIT_CODE=$?

# check jest exit code
if [ $JEST_EXIT_CODE -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Please you can do better than this.."
    exit 1
else
    echo "test all good.."
fi

# return 0-exit code
echo " you are a rockstar.."
exit 0
```

**related information**

- project files are located on linux distro network drive/partition

**related resources**

1. https://www.antstack.io/blog/adding-git-hooks-to-your-project/
2. https://dev.to/krzysztofkaczy9/do-you-really-need-husky-247b